# What are the differences between AbstractEventLoop.create_server and asyncio.start_server?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to understand the differences between

- `AbstractEventLoop.create_server()`
- `asyncio.start_server()`

and why one might choose one of these options over the other.

The relevant documentation pages can be found

- for `AbstractEventLoop.create_server()` [here](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_server)
- for `asyncio.start_server()` [here](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.start_server)

From the documentation they appear to be very similar.

The differences as far as I currently understand are:

- `start_server` speaks in terms of `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`. These are "higher level" objects compared to their counterparts (not sure exactly what the counterpart is right now). What the detailed consequences of this being "higher level" are for the user I also don't yet fully understand
- `create_server` requires a `Protocol` object to be specified. If I understand correctly, the programmer has to define a `class MyProtocol` which inherits from `asyncio.Protocol` and defines implementations for some common callbacks for "events" such as `connection_made`. Documentation link [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#protocols)

Other than knowing a few details about the differences I don't have any detailed understanding of what the intended purpose of each of these options are.

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same. They are used to create single-threaded server sockets to listen for incoming connections.

The difference lies in their level of abstraction.

- `asyncio.start_server()` is the high-level api that abstracts away some of the complexities involved in setting up a server.
- `AbstractEventLoop.create_server()` is the low-level api that gives you more control over the creation of the server.

In fact, from the documentation, we can notice that `asyncio.start_server()` invokes `AbstractEventLoop.create_server()`.

If you want to implement a standard server behavior, use `asyncio.start_server()`. But if you need more control over how the server is created (eg. choosing the socket family, setting up SSL/TLS, and more), use `AbstractEventLoop.create_server()`.